# Unable to sort in reverse using PipeTransform in angular4

Tags: html, angular

I am unable to sort the data. I refered from this website -

http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1211/angular-2-search-and-sort-with-ngfor-repeater-with-example

My data is not getting sorted in descending order -

Code -

**transaction.component.ts** file -->

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'orderBy' })

export class TransactionComponent implements OnInit,PipeTransform {

 isDesc: boolean = false;
 direction;
 column;

 sort(property){
 this.direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
 this.isDesc = !this.isDesc; //change the direction    
 this.column = property;

  };

 transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
   return records.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a[args.property] < b[args.property]){
      console.log("clicked on first")
        return -1 *args.direction;
    }
    else if( a[args.property] > b[args.property]){
      console.log("clicked on second")
        return 1 *args.direction;
    }
    else{
      console.log("clicked on third")
        return 0;
    }
  });
  };
  }
```

**transaction.component.html** -->

```
<tr *ngfor="let dat of result | filter:filterdata| orderBy : 
{property: 'LOG_ID',direction:direction } | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 
5, currentPage: p };let i = index ">
```

Comment: ok so what you are expecting sort an array  and have an option to make the sorting in descending or ascending order right?

Comment: yeh .. i want in descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for sort-by pipe. Which handles all types of array `string`, `number` and `array of objects`. For array of objects you need to pass the key according to which you want to sort.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "sortBy"
})
export class SortByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(array: any[], reverse: boolean = false, prop?: string) {
    array=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
      return array;
    }
    if (array.length) {
      let sortedArray: any[];
      if (typeof array[0] === "string") {
        sortedArray = array.sort();
      }
      if (typeof array[0] === "number") {
        sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
      }
      if (typeof array[0] === "object" && prop) {
        sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => a[prop].toString().localeCompare(b[prop].toString()));
      }
      if (reverse) {
        return sortedArray.reverse();
      } else {
        return sortedArray;
      }
    }
    return array;
  }
}
```

import it and add to declaration in your AppModule. And below is how to use.

```
<span>{{['asd', 'def', 'bghi', 'nhm'] | sortBy: reverse}}</span>
<br>
<span>{{[2, 8, 3, 6, 34, 12] | sortBy: reverse}}</span>
<br>
<span>{{[{name:'name2'} , {name:'name1'} , {name:'name3'}] | sortBy: reverse : 'name' | json}}</span>
```

[Here is a demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-huvvn1)

With this you can pass a boolean value that decide the reverse order or not. Also you can toggle that Just click the button it will change the order.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hey manish , this code is not working on UAT and Production. It is only working on localhost.... does it have any dependencies tht need to be looked after or any thing to be written exceptionally in module.ts

Comment: Thats strange. You are including the pipe in declaration array?

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let dat of result |orderBy: reverse : 'LOG_ID' |filter:filterdata | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p };let i = index ">  --> this is my declaration

Comment: The data in production and everywhere i.e. UAT and Localhost  is already in ascending order...i only want to reverse it. But this particular code is not applicable for large amount of data it seems

Comment: It should work irrespective of the length of data. Let me have a look and get back to you.

Comment: In your stackblitz you included it in a separate file ...but in my code i have included the transform and @ Pipe declaration in the same transaction.component.ts file like i defined in my question. Is that the issue ?

Comment: It may be or may not be. But its a good practice to keeps them in different files. For maintainability purpose. Also one file should export one module as per ES6. So its worth giving a try to keep both in different files and see if issue is resolved

Comment: Can you look into this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507172/i-am-unable-to-validate-the-date-properly-in-angular4?noredirect=1#comment88027193_50507172