# The pipe 'reverse' could not be found

Tags: html, angular, pipe

My data is arranged in ascending order... and i want it in descending order. I am using angular4.
For this i am using a reverse pipe. The code for the same is as below. The first time i used it...it worked ..but later from second time onwards it has started giving error as --> The pipe 'reverse' could not be found.

This is were i referred the code from -

[Invert Angular 2 *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703258/invert-angular-2-ngfor)

**transaction.component.ts**

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({  
  name: 'reverse',
  pure:false
 })


export class TransactionComponent implements OnInit ,PipeTransform{

transform (values: any) {
 if (values) {
  return values.slice().reverse();
   }
  }

 .....//code
 }
```

**transaction.component.html**

```
 <tr *ngFor="let dat of result |reverse |  filter:filterdata| 
  paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p };let i = index ">
```

Comment: Did you declare your pipe in a module?

Comment: I just added  -->import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';  in my master.module.ts.... anywhere we need to declare it in  imports or declarations ?

Comment: Yeah you need to add your pipe to the declarations array

Comment: please show you json data

Comment: this is part of my json - "TESTNODE_root"
BTID
:
"1_BUQPT2554D_20180410-172211"
CORREL_ID
:
"000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
CREATED_BY
:
"SYSTEM"
CREATED_ON
:
"2018-04-10T11:52:13.000Z"
DESCRIPTION
:
null
ERROR_CD
:
null
ERROR_COMPONENT
:
null
ERROR_TYPE
:
null
EXCEPTION_PAYLOAD_ID
:
null
FILE_ID
:
null
INTERFACE_NAME
:
"Experian"
INW_TRN_ID
:
null
LOG_ID
:
2

Comment: i had a different approach  here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371770/unable-to-sort-using-pipetransform-in-angular4/50371886#50371886  ......but it is not working ... can you please check it

Answer (score 1):

The below code declares a pipe.
**reverse.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({  
  name: 'reverse',
  pure:false
 })


export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform{

transform (values: any) {
 if (values) {
  return values.slice().reverse();
   }
  }

 .....//code
 }
```

In order to use it in your app.You need to import the pipe and add it to the declarations in your module like below.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReversePipe } from '../path/to/yourpipe'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ReversePipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Working demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oarrra)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey Manish, ...is it necessary to define a ReversePipe differently... because i am defining its content TransactionComponent  and it is already defined in my  declarations : [TransactionComponent] ...  i have written the code as it is in my question. It that declaration not correct. Because you seem to define another .ts file where the reverse function code is kept

Comment: And in your stackblitz ... the hello is not printed in reverse ... sorry to notice

Comment: i had a different approach  here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371770/unable-to-sort-using-pipetransform-in-angular4/50371886#50371886  ......but it is not working

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava yes the code is not to print it in reverse. Thats just a demo. Will edit it to print it in reverse. Yes it is a good practice to define it seperately. Also component and Pipe are two different things. Can read more about them in offical docs

Comment: Have updated the demo. Will print in reverse. Also you will have to implement proper logic to handle different value. Currently it will work for only  strings

Answer (score 0):

Add your pipe to declarations array in your module.

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
       // import and add your pipe to this.
   ],

   imports: [

   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: if i add to declarations : [Pipe] ...i get this error ... Error: Unexpected value 'DecoratorFactory' declared by the module 'MasterSystemModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.  .... Also, i  have  defined my component name in declarations :[TransactionComponent]

Comment: i had a different approach  here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371770/unable-to-sort-using-pipetransform-in-angular4/50371886#50371886  ......but it is not working... can you please check it